# jQuery Mobile - disable default selected state of input field

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, input

I've got an accordion with an input field which is collapsed by default. When I click the accordion it is expanded and a text input field and two buttons show up. When the text input field shows up it is selected by default (i.e. the cursor is blinking in the input field). I want to disable that - I want the user to physically select the field first.

The reason for this is because on lower-end handsets when the accordion is clicked, the keyboard pops up on the screen before jQuery is executed and form shows up on the screen and it looks really bad. If the form was not selected initially, the keyboard would only pop up on  the screen once the form is selected by the user.

Here's the code for the collapsible list

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-collapsed="true" class="question">

<h3>Name</h3>   

    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ux-field-contain ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">
        <label for="answer" class="ui-input-text">answer</label>
        <input type="text" data-role="button" autofocus = "on" autocomplete = "off" data-theme="b" name="answer" value="Save">
    </div>

    <div data-theme="b">
        <input data-role="button" data-theme="b" name="save" value="Save"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```